# How do you count Spring Actuator requests with Prometheus?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to count the number of requests to `/actuator/health` and `/metrics` with the Prometheus API for Spring. Normally, I just `inc()` my counter in whatever endpoint I have defined, but I don't want to have to make my own `actuator/health` endpoint just to increment a counter. I don't want to use micrometer because I am using Spring 2 and micrometer torpedoes my build. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK `/actuator/health` is an internal endpoint of spring actuator and you don't have access to that to add your `counter.inc()`. What are the approaches that you already tried? Why do you have those strict requeriments?

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been finding... kinda sad that incrementing counters is tied to method implementation. I tried to make a request interceptor but that did not work because actuator requests are handled by a different handler. Now this is no longer a requirement. Thanks!